# How can I frequently update a file without harming my disk?

Tags: performance, i3, ssd, optimization

I've got an i3 install on a laptop with an SSD. Currently I have it configured to save the WM layout on many different events. The tool that I'm using to do this is built on Python, and I'm just running it with an ampersand through the i3 config. However, I'm concerned that this will hurt the longevity of my disk. I understand a bit about the "virtual filesystem", but I'm not really sure how that applies here. Should I be concerned about my disk? And if so, how can I change my setup to avoid that, while still being able to frequently update this table (which is stored as multiple json files).

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting timing having this question asked immediately before https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650082/117549! The first thing that comes to mind is a ram disk that's occasionally copied to a hard disk.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  First, your operating system caches updates to a file so every update you do doesn't go directly to disk.  Second, most disks have caches that do the same.  Third, [SSDs last longer than you seem to think](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssd+lifetime).